# How to divide total and single value in one column using PowerBI?

Tags: powerbi, dax, calculated-columns, divide

I do need your favor. I need to do calculation by divide a total column with single value in that column itself.

Here is the my table looks like:
[image]

My expectation is, I need to divide one of the category which is `Hardware` with the total of the score which is `470`
The result supposed to be `44/470 = 0.09`

This is what I've tried:

```
DIVIDE(COUNTROWS(FILTER(Factory,Factory[Category]="Hardware")),Factory[Total Score])
```

But it return `470`.
Anyone could help with this problem please? Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

don't know your database like. try this sentence:
=calculate(COUNTROWS('Factory'),'Factory'[Category]="Hardware",allexcept('Factory','Factory'[Category]))/calculate(countrows('Factory'),all('Factory'))

if does not work let me see your database.

Comment: Hi @Sia it does not work

Comment: let me see your database.

Comment: the image you show i think is not the database in powerbi. calculation should be based on database of course.